ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dal' en un proyecto Django que corre en un contenedor Docker
"Instalé" dal en mi proyecto de Django que corre sobre un contenedor de docker y al levantar el contenedor el servidor me devuelve
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dal'
ERROR:root:Error including dal_select2.urls: No module named 'dal_select2'

Lo instalé desde pip primero
pip install django-autocomplete-light

luego probé
pip install -e git+https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light.git

También agregué en el repositorio en el requirements.txt
django-autocomplete-light==3.11.0

Agregué las líneas en settings.py del proyecto
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'dal',
'dal_select2',
'dal_queryset_sequence',
'django.contrib.admin',

Agregué el código en urls.py de mi proyecto
urlpatterns = [
    path('autocomplete/', include('dal_select2.urls')),

Instalé, reinstalé, bajé, eliminé y creé el contenedor con docker-compose build --no-cache y sigo obteniendo el mismo error. También verifiqué la instalación dentro y fuera del contenedor. No sé más qué hacer.
